# Storing Blog Comments/Upvotes - Tracking Users?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3, database-design, schema

I am working on a blog-type website in ASP .net MVC3. I am trying to figure out how I will deal with post upvotes/downvotes(I will have to know what users have already voted where to prevent spam voting). Comments on a blog post is another issue.

My thoughts so far(I am sure they are pretty far off the mark):

**Votes:**

- Store a list of UserIDs in a voted field of my Blog table.
- For each user in my Users table, store a list of all PostIDs they have voted on.

**Comments:**

- Make a separate Comments table and in that table have a field referencing the parent blog post.
- Store a list of CommentIDs in a Comment field in my Blogs table.

I know there are several other ways to go about this but I am trying to set this up so that I won't have to rewrite the whole thing should I get an influx of users.

Comment: sounds like stackoverflow design to me

Comment: I wasn't aware of stackoverflow design. Do you mean a design tag? Added a design tag. Thanks.

Comment: What I mean is your requirement sounds just like what stackoverflow currently have Up/Down vote and remembers by user id etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might wanna consider creating a Votes table like
User|Post|Type?
john|43  |Up
mary|43  |Down

making User + Post a composite primary key, and thus indexing by both... Then you can easily check if a user has already voted for a post or not... You can also create additional indexes by user or post if needed...

I'd also be a good idea then to have the "Current Ups and Current Downs" in the blogs table, so you don't have to count them each time...

Comment: Very insightful, thanks. I worked out the comments portion and was wondering how I was going to do voting. This seems to be a solid implementation.